# How to place the inflection point of a polyline in the center of a histogram in echarts

Tags: echarts

[Click here to see the charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a1vy.png)

I want to place the inflection point of the polyline in the center of the red histogram.I browsed the documentation of echarts, but could not find the corresponding configuration.Is there any way to do it?

I have found a working method, but it doesn't work for my current chart. Because my chart also includes the dataZoom component. When I zoom in and out of a chart, its data layout becomes messy.Here is the method i found(https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000018354786):

```html
option = {
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross',
            crossStyle: {
                color: '#999'
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'category',
        data: ['1月', '2月', '3月', '4月', '5月', '6月', '7月', '8月', '9月', '10月', '11月', '12月'],
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    }, ],
    yAxis: [{
            type: 'value',
            name: '水量',
            min: 0,
            max: 250,
            interval: 50,
            axisLabel: {
                formatter: '{value} ml'
            }
        }
    ],
    series: [{
            name: '柱1',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3],
            z: 1
        },
        {
            name: '柱2',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3],
            z: 1

        },
        {
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            name: '线1',
            type: 'line',
            itemStyle:{
                normal:{
                    lineStyle:{
                        color: '#c23c31',
                        type:'dotted' //'dotted'虚线 'solid'实线
                    }
                }
            }, 
            data: [2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3],
        },
        {
            xAxisIndex: 1,
            name: '线2',
            type: 'line',
            itemStyle:{
                normal:{
                    lineStyle:{
                        color: '#2f4554',
                        type:'dotted'
                    }
                }
            }, 
            data: [2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3],
        }
    ]
};

// 增加了一个隐藏的x轴，用来控制线图的点的位置
option.xAxis[1] = {
    type: 'value',
    max: option.xAxis[0].data.length * 100,
    show: false
}
option.series[2].data = option.series[2].data.map((x, i) => [27 + i * 100, x])
option.series[3].data = option.series[3].data.map((x, i) => [73 + i * 100, x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some xAxes in chart for each series but dataZoom [don't know about it](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-inside.xAxisIndex).
Just add `xAxisIndex: [0,1]` to dataZoom for use all axes and it will work.

```js
dataZoom: [{
  [...]
  xAxisIndex: [0,1]
  }, {
  [...]
}]
```